# Why all weights become zeros in this code?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am trying to make a singer classification on TensorFlow 2. However, when I trained my model, I found all weights finally become to zero matrices. I am not sure why this problem occurs. Please let me know.

The following code is the simplest version of my problem. I tested this code on TF2.1, TF2.2rc0, TF2.2rc3, but the results were same.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

audios = tf.keras.layers.Input(
    shape= [None,],
    dtype= tf.float32
    )
singers = tf.keras.layers.Input(
    shape= [],
    dtype= tf.int32
    )

new_Tensor = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis= -1))(audios)    #[Batch, T, 1]
new_Tensor = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(new_Tensor) #[Batch, T, 128]
new_Tensor = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis= 1))(new_Tensor)    #[Batch, 128]
new_Tensor = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12)(new_Tensor)  #[Batch, 12]

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate= 0.002
    )

model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs= audios,
    outputs= new_Tensor
    )
model.summary()

while True:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # audios = np.random.rand(3, 16000) * 2 - 1
        singers = np.random.randint(0, 12, 3)
        audios = np.zeros((3, 16000)) + np.expand_dims(singers, axis= -1)

        logits = model(audios, training= True)        
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
            y_true= singers,
            y_pred= logits
            ))

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients([
        (gradient, variable)
        for gradient, variable in zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables)
        ])
    print(loss)
    for gradient, variable in zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables):
        print('{}: {}'.format(variable.name, gradient))
```

**EDIT :**

I found a answer. 'tf.keras.losses' does not work without compile. When I changed them to 'tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits', it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Few things here:

1. Given the shapes you want to feed into the model, the inputs should be:

   ```
   audios = tf.keras.layers.Input(
       shape= [None, 1],
       dtype= tf.float32
   )
   singers = tf.keras.layers.Input(
       shape= [128],
       dtype= tf.int32
   )
   ```
2. In your training loop, check that the shapes for addition are broadcastable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, input shape was not problem because first layer of sequence is  expand dims and singer is also sparse target..